# stop warpper div from moving when scaling browser

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page that has a wrapper with a background color on it. When I scale the browser in to a small size the wrapper pops out of position. Its like 20px at the left was added.

Also when you scale the browser in small the input fields drop down to the next line. How can I stop that.

http://www.artaholic.com/push/bc/acc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
```

if you not really need it. It'll solve the jump.

Answer (score 0):

The 20px from bootstrap responsive , this line I believe:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
```